# Identifying whether an integer over a certain value appears before a non-numerical char does C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, integer

I'm wanting to read through a file and identify if a letter character appears before an integer value which is above 10. The items in the file are separated by a space and at the end of the list is an "endl;".

So far, I tried getting an array of the integers in the file (just by reading in the arrays and checking if any are above 10) and equally, I've been reading characters in through the file and checking if any are not a digit, but I can't work out how to compare the positions of a non-digit character and too-large integer that I find? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
// i.e. sample file may contain:
1 2 3 A 6 12 90 //(in which case the letter appears first).
// example two:
34A 20 4 5 6 7 //(large number here appears first).
```

Comment: Are the char and int the same item or separated by space? A sample file content would help

Comment: @KillzoneKid the char and int may or may not be the same item. I.e. the file may be "1 2 3 A 6 12 90" (n which case the letter appears first).

Comment: `1 2 3 A 6 12 90` so this is a fail, right? A is before 6 which is < 10

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: @ventsyv no its not, its part of a project I'm working on but I want to report errors if the input file has random/stray data that is not relevant for the next part.

Comment: If you read character by character and you find 2 characters that are digits in a row before you find a letter, you've found an error. Hmmm maybe not. 01 would fail that test. A step in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. The following will find two or more digits followed by a letter

```
\d{2,}[a-zA-Z]
```

This will work unless you have zero padded numericals (for example 01a)

Depending on the C++ standard you are targeting, you might be able to use `<regex>`. More info on that [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)

[Here is an example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) how to return all matches.

Comment: Most of the time regex is _overshoot_ for such simple parsing problems.

Comment: I disagree. You can write a regex search function in less than 10 lines of code.

Comment: You can do his with good old `std::istream` text extraction methods in less than 10 lines of code as well, so what?

Comment: So when your boss comes and tells you to add all those special cases, you can simply modify your regex instead of writing a whole lot of code for them.

Comment: So when your boss comes and says: _"Why is that file record hashing so frickin' slow? What did you do there??"_, you should also be prepared to have a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array, you just need keep track of which one you encounter first.

Something like this:

- Define a variable letter_first
- As long a there is input:

  - Read one thing
  - If it's a letter, then it occurs before an integer > 10; set letter_first to true and break out of the loop
  - If it's a number greater than 10, then it occurs before a letter; set letter_first to false and break out of the loop
  - Otherwise, continue with the next item
- Use the result

Comment: but how would I read in an integer (which can consist of 2 digits) versus a character? You're reply is making it sound like you can read in one integer as one character?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect that you learned how to turn a string of digits into an integer not that long ago. So instead of reading an integer, you read a string, then convert it into an integer if it's not a letter.